# Subset of a cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $N$ and $N'$ be two sets. Is it possible that $N \subseteq N \times N'$?

I don't think so, but actually I am not able to get any absurd sentences supposing that is true.

Let us suppose that $N \subseteq N \times N'$. Then, for any $x \in N$ there exist $n \in N$, $n' \in N'$, such that $x = (n,n')$. But then there exist $m \in N$, $m' \in N'$, such that $n=(m,m')$, $x=((m,m'),n)$ and so on. I see it is ugly, but I can't understand why it is absurd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $N\subseteq N\times N'$, and let $n_0\in N$; then there are $n_1\in N$ and $n_1'\in N'$ such that $n_0=\langle n_1,n_1'\rangle$. In general, given $n_k\in N$ we must have $n_{k+1}\in N$ and $n_{k+1}'\in N'$ such that $n_k=\langle n_{k+1},n_{k+1}'\rangle$, and in this way we can recursively define a sequence $\langle n_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ in $N$.

Now $\langle x,y\rangle=\big\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\big\}$, so $x\in\{x\}\in\langle x,y\rangle$. Thus,

$$\ldots\in n_3\in\{n_3\}\in n_2\in\{n_2\}\in n_1\in\{n_1\}\in n_0$$

is an infinite descending $\in$-chain, which violates the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

Comment: @BrianMScott I can't understand you when you say $\langle x,y\rangle=\big\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\big\}$

Comment: It is a definition of $\langle x,y \rangle$.

Comment: @MStawiski I see it is a definition of an element $\langle x,y\rangle$ of a cartesian product of two sets as a set containing two sets, but I have never met something like this. Can you explain me this definition or, maybe, can you give me some references?

Comment: @Imre: You could start with the [discussion of ordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) in Wikipedia; this one is due to Kuratowski and has beome standard in set theory. $\big\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\big\}$ is one of the simplest sets definable from arbitrary $x$ and $y$ that has the properties that we want an ordered pair to have: $\big\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\big\}=\big\{\{u\},\{u,v\}\big\}$ if and only if $x=u$ and $y=v$, and $x$ and $y$ are recoverable from $\big\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\big\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if and only if $N$ is an empty set.